# confusion with Java programming

Tags: java

I have started learning core Java and one particular thing is driving me crazy. I know how create a object

something like

```
Mouse mouse = new Mouse ();
```

However what I don't understand is whether these are objects too:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("");
```

If not - what are they? Would really appreciate if someone can clear my confusion.

Comment: The technique of having an object with a method which creates and returns a new objects is called the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `conn`, `st`, and `rs1` in your samples are all objects, just like `mouse`. You are creating a mouse with a *constructor*, like so:

```
Mouse mouse = new Mouse()
```

But you just as easily could add a `static` method to your `Mouse` that would create a new instance of `mouse`, just like `DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);` returns a new instance of `Statement`. For example:

```
public class Mouse {

    public Mouse() { }

    public static Mouse createNewMouse() { 
        return new Mouse();
    }

 }
```

Then instead of using the constructor you could just as easily say

```
Mouse mouse = Mouse.createNewMouse();
```

In the case of the `Mouse` class, there is no good reason to use static method like that. As some of the comments have mentioned, however, there is something called the [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which is a design pattern that can hide some of the complexity of instantiating complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

We can expand your mouse example:

```
class Mouse {
  private String name;

  public Mouse() {
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Mouse makeDropping() {
    return new Dropping(this);
  }

  public static Mouse createMouse(String name) {
    Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
    mouse.setName(name);
    return mouse;  
  }
}

class Dropping {
  private Mouse;

  public Dropping(Mouse mouse) {
    this.mouse = mouse;
  }

  public String mouseName() {
    return this.mouse.getName();
  } 
}
```

---

We can create a mouse object using the constructor:

```
Mouse mickey = new Mouse();
mickey.setName("Mickey");
```

`new Mouse()` creates the object, `mickey` is a reference to that object.

We can also create a mouse using the static factory method of the Mouse class:

```
Mouse jerry = Mouse.createMouse("Jerry");
```

`Mouse.createMouse("Jerry")` returns a reference to the Mouse object it created and we set it to `jerry`.

---

Now if we call the `makeDropping()` method on either `Mouse`, they return a `Dropping` object.

```
Dropping mickeyDropping = mickey.makeDropping();
Dropping jerryDropping = jerry.makeDropping();
```

We don't need to know where the `Dropping` object is created, we still have a reference to a `Dropping` object.

---

```
String name1 = mickeyDropping.mouseName();
String name2 = jerryDropping.mouseName();
```

Calling the `mouseName()` method on the Dropping objects also returns references, this time to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Yes : conn, st and rs1 are objects (instances), even if you didn't instantiate them directly.

For example conn:

- Maybe it was instanciated by getConnection,
- maybe it was instanciated by a method called by getConnection,
- maybe it was already existing and getConnection just returned it.